# Upgrade electrical panel

Tags: electrical

I am upgrading panels at my apartment complex and presently only have 3 wire coming from main breakers at a meter bank and don’t have access to run new SER 4 wire

Can I just use existing 3 wire and use green bonding screws in the neutral bus and then add additional ground bus?

The inspector says that’s ok.

Comment: The inspector is god, we are only lowly slugs.

Comment: Can you post a photo of where the existing wiring enters your existing subpanel?

Comment: Why would you run 4 fat wires when you only need 1 little one? The retrofit ground rules are clear, you can just run a #6 bare ground.   You can't do that for a new installation but for a retrofit, yeah.

Comment: Does "apartment" mean "rental"? If so, and if you happen to be in the US, what you're doing is illegal. I'd guess my assumptions are wrong, however, since you seem to have had an inspector out and he hasn't screamed at you about it. Either that, or your are the _owner_ of the apartment complex, and in that case, it should be your _licensed_ electrician doing the work. (All bets are off if not in the US, though I understand that rules against DIY are more strict in many EU countries).